# Select specific table cell in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML like this:

```
<table id="laboral">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="start"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="end"/></td>
        <td><textarea name="desc"></textarea></td>
        <td><button type="button" onclick="saveValues(this);createRow('laboral')"> + </button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What I want is to save the values in the three cells (2 inputs and 1 textarea).

The button creates another row just like the first, with the same inputs and names. The problem is that I don't know how to access THIS row, I mean, the row who owns the button.

I tried with this.parentNode.parentNode but didn't work.

Comment: You'll need to pass `this` to `createRow`. Then it should be `[[yourParameterName]].parentNode.parentNode` instead of `this.parentNode.parentNode`. Or change the call to `createRow.call(this, "laboral")` so that you can use `this.parentNode.parentNode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<table id="laboral">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="start"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="end"/></td>
        <td><textarea name="desc"></textarea></td>
        <td><button type="button" onclick="saveValues(this)"> + </button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
var inputVals = [];

function saveValues(elm) {
    //         button   td         tr        tbody     table
    var table = elm.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;

    //  iterating through the first row cells
    for (var i = 0; i<table.rows[0].cells.length-1; i++) {
        //  the current cell
        var cell = table.rows[0].cells[i];
        //  pushing the input elm's value into the array
        inputVals.push(cell.childNodes[0].value);
        //  retrieving the pushed value
        alert(inputVals[i]);
    }
}
```

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/zg9zS/1/)

You can modify the code.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a reference to the button into `saveValues`, so within `saveValues` the first argument will refer to the button. Let's call that argument `btn.` `btn.parentNode` will be the `td` containing the button, and `` `btn.parentNode.parentNode `` will be the `tr` containing that `td`. So:

```
function saveValues(btn) {
    var tr = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
    // Work with `childNodes` and the `childNodes` of those children to get the values
}
```

Comment: I'm trying this and doesn't work:
var tr = button.parentNode.parentNode;
alert(tr.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].value);

Comment: I don't know why, but I need to use tr.childNodes[1] to acces to the first td of the tr